# Should there be a moderator flag for cross-posting?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, cross-posting, flags

When a question is cross-posted from another StackExchange site, such as Superuser, I assume that we do not want the question duplicated on Unix and Linux. It is bad etiquette for someone to do so, and questions can be moved between sites.

When flagging a post for moderator attention, there is an "exact duplicate" option. This option requires linking to a question on U&L, and does not allow linking to another SE site. Should there be a separate flag for cross-posting?

Comment: yes, but I brought this up on meta SE and they said no, feel free to take it up on there again though IMO

Comment: @xenoterracide Thanks, I found your original question on meta SO. It looks like the recommendation is to flag as OT, which seems wrong in some cases as it may not be OT. I feel a need to downvote cross-posts, but that may not be appropriate action either.

Comment: Have you got some examples that annoy you? I can think of a number of cases, where x-posts might make sense (if you want an answer with the focus of that site).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we get rid of the "cross-posted" close reason?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3422/should-we-get-rid-of-the-cross-posted-close-reason)

Comment: @Scott how can my post be a duplicate of a question asked 1.5 years later about a feature that may exist because of this question?

Comment: Surely you know that chronological order is not a determiner for which question gets closed.  The two questions cover the exact same subject, and your question is obsoleted by this feature (that may exist because of this question), so this is the one that (IMHO) should be closed.

Comment: @jordanm Treat "duplicate" to mean "there is an answer to this question over there". That seems to be more or less how we use it. Though I don't think it's a duplicate under that definition..

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag for cross posting. Click **should be closed…** , **off-topic**, then **This question has been posted on multiple sites. Cross-posting is strongly discouraged; see the help center and community FAQ for more information.**

Note: the **should be closed** option only appears if you have 50 or more reputation, so you must have at least 50 reputation to use this flag.